# Make a form submit() behave like location.replace()

Tags: javascript

IN SHORT:

There's this web page that needs to be submitted when the user loads the page. There is a good reason for it, long story.

Would it be possible to make a form `post` submit() behave like a location.replace()? No history trace.

Thanks.

---

LONG STORY: In my CMS, I have one page for each product. Products are normally listed on section pages, where the user is invited to *choose a product* :

1. Small $10 *BUY*
2. Medium $20 *BUY*
3. Large $30 *BUY*

Clicking on *BUY* would send the user to the payment page, off-site.

The product details come from the CMS page, where I defined specific fields for price, product ID, etc. Product detailes are rendered as a form.

I basically don't want to show the independent, permalink product pages, ever. But, this being a CMS, the products will be listed on section pages and whatnot, and the user may end up choosing the products by clicking on a link instead of the full rendered page with the form.

If they do end up on the product page, I want them to be redirected to the purchase page. Of course I don't want to keep the page in history, for the same reasons location.replace() was invented: to avoid the back button of eternal redirection.

Comment: Don't think so. Using location.replace causes the browser to issue a GET. There's only a url parameter, you can't use `.replace(url, 'POST')` (which would possibly be nice).

Comment: Why not post the form using Ajax?

Comment: I'm guessing you want to display the POST response.  Why don't you want the user to access their browser history?  Seriously, your reasons are going to be either misguided or otherwise your approach is out of date.

Comment: Lee, you are right about wanting to display the POST response. I don't care about accessing the browsing history, just want to avoid locking the back button in a redirect trap.  
I added a long description to make it clear what I want and why I have to do it like this.

Answer (score 2):

Just do an AJAX POST followed by a `location.replace`.  The AJAX POST won't create a browser history entry.

Comment: I want to redirect the user to the form result page off site.

Comment: If by "redirect" you mean you server's HTTP 30X response has the proper "Location" header, you can read that in the ajax response and do location.replace with that URL.  If by "redirect" you mean you want the user to "end up at" a given URL, that URL can be the response body of the form POST request.